# Why am I getting an invalid identifier in this query for the table in the From Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this query below:

```
Select b.b_id as Business_id, b.business_name, Average_Rating, b.review_count AS Review_count
FROM (
    SELECT b.b_id AS Business_id, AVG(r.rating) AS Average_Rating
    FROM Business b
    JOIN Business_Category bc ON b.bc_id = bc.bc_id
    JOIN Review r ON b.b_id = r.b_id
    WHERE bc.category_name = 'Breakfast and Brunch' AND b.city = 'San Jose' AND b.state = 'CA'
    GROUP BY b.b_id
) t_one
INNER JOIN Business b_one ON t_one.b_id = b_one.b_id
ORDER BY Average_Rating DESC, Review_count DESC, Business_Id ASC;
```

I am getting in `invalid identifier` on this line: `INNER JOIN Business b_one ON t_one.b_id = b_one.b_id` for `t_one`.

Error:

> ORA-00904: "T_ONE"."B_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: there is no t_one.b_id as you named that field as Business_id inside the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your alias b is not within the scope of your outer query.

```
SELECT b_one.b_id as Business_id, b_one.business_name, Average_Rating, b_one.review_count AS Review_count
FROM (
    SELECT b.b_id AS Business_id, AVG(r.rating) AS Average_Rating
    FROM Business b
    JOIN Business_Category bc ON b.bc_id = bc.bc_id
    JOIN Review r ON b.b_id = r.b_id
    WHERE bc.category_name = 'Breakfast and Brunch' AND b.city = 'San Jose' AND b.state = 'CA'
    GROUP BY b.b_id
) t_one
INNER JOIN Business b_one ON t_one.b_id = b_one.b_id
ORDER BY Average_Rating DESC, Review_count DESC, Business_Id ASC;
```